# How can I remove the <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> of Joomla?

Tags: php, html, joomla, character-encoding, header

How can i remove the `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

on this PHP Joomla Template? Because I have a Duplication of the Meta Tag from Joomla and from the Template :/ The `Head.php` file it is calling is:

```
<meta charset="<?php echo $this['system']->document->getCharset(); ?>">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<?php if($this['config']->get('responsive', true)): ?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (isset($error)): ?>
<title><?php echo $error; ?> - <?php echo $title; ?></title>
<?php else: ?>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

and the `Index.php` is:

```
// get theme configuration
include($this['path']->path('layouts:theme.config.php'));

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="<?php echo $this['config']->get('language'); ?>" dir="<?php echo $this['config']->get('direction'); ?>"  data-config='<?php echo $this['config']->get('body_config','{}'); ?>'>

    <head>
    <?php echo $this['template']->render('head'); ?>
    </head>

    <body class="<?php echo $this['config']->get('body_classes'); ?>">
```

here is an Image of this Problem:
[Link to the Problem ( imgur )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6JjV.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your problem right. Do you want to remove the duplicate chartset?
Simple remove the first line in your first code sample.
And you can try `$doc->setHtml5(true);`in the index.php

Comment: Yes, thats what I want :) Sorry for this Dumb Question... I am a noob with PHP where would I put the `$doc->setHtml5(true);` in the index.php ?

Comment: Put <?php $doc->setHtml5(true); ?> anywhere in the Head section or better in an existing <?php --- ?> in the head.

Comment: If I remove `<meta charset="<?php echo $this['system']->document->getCharset(); ?>">` it doesnt render the Head at all :/

Comment: This should only remove this line in the head. Mybe something wrong with your Editor by converting the file by saving.

Comment: Okay, i fixed it :) The Problem was that i needed to call the Document :)  `<?php
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->setHtml5(true);
?>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">`

Comment: Congratulation. Now you have a valid html5 header and a valid utf-8 meta ;-)

Comment: Maybe it depends on the template, but I could obtain the same solution by putting `$this->setHtml5(true);` in the beggining of `index.php` (`$this`seems to be the current `Document`)